# How can one add a label to a Markdown box in Gradio?

Tags: python, gradio

I tried:

```
import gradio as gr
with gr.Blocks(css="footer{display:none !important}") as demo:
    answer = gr.Markdown(value='[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)', label="Answer")
demo.launch(share=True)
```

but to my surprise, the label "Answer" doesn't appear in the UI:

[image]

I don't have that issue with `Textbox`:

E.g.,

```
import gradio as gr
with gr.Blocks(css="footer{display:none !important}") as demo:
    answer = gr.Textbox(value='[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)', label="Answer")
demo.launch(share=True)
```

will display the label "Answer" for the textbox:

[image]

How can one add a label to a Markdown box in Gradio?

I use Gradio 4.16.0 with Python 3.11.7 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

[yuvi](https://twitter.com/yvrjsharma) posted this [great answer](https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1025174734427656283/threads/1205659532051750972) on Discord:

> `label` doesn't work the same way for `gr.HTML` and `gr.markdown` as it does for other components.
> Example for intended use of the label param  in both these components :
>
> ```py
> import gradio as gr
> with gr.Blocks() as demo:
>     answerhtml = gr.HTML(value='''<a href='https://hf.co//'>huggingface</a>''', label="Answer HTML")
>     answer = gr.Markdown(value='[gradio](https://gradio.app/)', label="Answer Markdown")
>
>     gr.Examples([
>         ['[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)', '''<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>'''],
>         ['[google](https://google.com/)', '''<a href='https://google.com/'>google</a>''']
>     ], [answer, answerhtml])
> demo.launch(share=True)
> ```
>
> Here, you'll see that the labels for these two are used as headers for the example table below your app:
>
> [image]
>
> One way to add a label could be to encase the markdown in an gr.Accordion and keep it open by default:
>
> ```py
> import gradio as gr
> with gr.Blocks() as demo:
>   with gr.Accordion('Answers:', open=True):
>     answerhtml = gr.HTML(value='''<a href='https://hf.co//'>huggingface</a>''', label="Answer HTML")
>     answer = gr.Markdown(value='[gradio](https://gradio.app/)', label="Answer Markdown")
>
>   gr.Examples([
>         ['[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)', '''<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>'''],
>         ['[google](https://google.com/)', '''<a href='https://google.com/'>google</a>''']
>     ], [answer, answerhtml])
> demo.launch(share=True)
> ```
>
> What else you can do is add headings as h1/h2/h3 tags within an HTML component or use hashtags within your markdown examples.
>
> [image]
>
> ```py
> import gradio as gr
> val = '''<h1>Answers</h1>
> '''
> with gr.Blocks() as demo:
>     heading = gr.HTML(value=val)
>     answerhtml = gr.HTML(value='''<a href='https://hf.co//'>huggingface</a>''', label="Answer HTML")
>     answer = gr.Markdown(value='[gradio](https://gradio.app/)', label="Answer Markdown")
>
>     gr.Examples([
>         ['[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)', '''<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>'''],
>         ['[google](https://google.com/)', '''<a href='https://google.com/'>google</a>''']
>     ], [answer, answerhtml])
> demo.launch(share=True)
> ```
>
> [image]

Based on that answer, I replaced:

```
import gradio as gr
with gr.Blocks(css="footer{display:none !important}") as demo:
    answer = gr.Markdown(value='[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)', label="Answer")
demo.launch()
```

with

```
import gradio as gr
with gr.Blocks(css="footer{display:none !important}") as demo:
    with gr.Accordion('Answer:', open=True):
        answer = gr.Markdown(value='[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)', label="")
demo.launch()
```

which gives:

[image]